# Memory Leak opening and closing a datasource with twain.dll

Tags: vb.net, memory-leaks, twain

I am writing an application which uses the twain_32.dll to access a scanner and scanning documents.
It worked properly but after 100 - 150 scans I get a memory issue and the application has to be closed to free the blocked memory.

I was able to determine one point where a problem seems to occur.

To access the scanner I have to open the Datasource using the following imported function:

```
<DllImport("twain_32.dll", EntryPoint:="#1")> Private Shared Function TwainOpenDatasource(<[In](), Out()> ByVal ApplicationIdentity As DataStructures.twIdentity, ByVal ZeroPointer As IntPtr, ByVal DataType As ITwain.DataGroup, ByVal Data As ITwain.DataArgumentTypes, ByVal Message As ITwain.Message, ByVal ScannerIdentity As DataStructures.twIdentity) As ITwain.ReturnCode
End Function
```

And after that I am closing the same Datasource in the intention to free the memory

```
<DllImport("twain_32.dll", EntryPoint:="#1")> Private Shared Function TwainCloseDatasource(<[In](), Out()> ByVal ApplicationIdentity As DataStructures.twIdentity, ByVal ZeroPointer As IntPtr, ByVal DataType As ITwain.DataGroup, ByVal Data As ITwain.DataArgumentTypes, ByVal Message As ITwain.Message, ByVal ScannerIdentity As DataStructures.twIdentity) As ITwain.ReturnCode
End Function
```

The problem is that after opening the datasource the application allocates around 1500k memory and on closing deallocates only 1000k.

Does anyone have an idea what the problem is? Do I have to clear something else by myself? Or is there any possibility to deallocate old memory manually?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Try calling GlobalFree function and see how it works.

Comment: I don't have a handle to free...Therefore GlobalFree won't help. Thanks for your reply anyway

Comment: Have any one figure out this problem? I have the same.